# How to register extended unit test attribute for Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to extend MS unit test class in Visual Studio 2013, in accordance with the guideline below.

[Extending the Visual Studio Unit Test Type, part 1](http://Extending%20the%20Visual%20Studio%20Unit%20Test%20Type,%20part%201)

But it does not works fine.

With my .pdb and .dll files copying to PrivateAssemblies folder under the VS installed directory, VS steps into extended TestClassAttribute to find ExtentionID, but the test method failed with the errormessage telling ***failed to initialize the unit test extension, as it is not registered***.

I really carefully inspected the registry hierarchy and entry to match the guideline and found no error.(Although the upper node of VS version is different from 10.0 to 12.0)

I wonder if ***is it possible to extend unit class in my VS 2013 version "Professional"***.

Also as far as I inspected, this issue is not so popular since VS 2013 was released.

***Is extending unit test class is still effective in VS 2013?***

I'll appreciate any hint, advice or solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have not tried this myself, and searching for it with VS2013 almost came up blank... Guess it might help if you post your code here - then someone can try (like me) to reproduce it. Have you found this blog, someone claims it might work without register hacks... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/04/28/extending-unit-tests-in-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Hi Jocke, thank you for you  advice.
I have put zip file of my solution on following http url.

http://www.ad.il24.net/~masa_cmt/StackOverflow/LoggingTest.zip

To simplify the problem, I have modified the source code so simple.
When you designate the url on browser, it will give you a security warning, but this zip will do no harm.

Comment: Contents of above program is in my other post in my msdn forum.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6ffaf34-0ce7-4e4e-859b-0cf5c285a695/could-it-be-possible-to-extend-unittestclass-in-visual-studio-20102013-professional-edition?forum=vsunittest#e6ffaf34-0ce7-4e4e-859b-0cf5c285a695

Comment: Hi, I will have a go at this tomorrow. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have reached to the solution.

Details in my self reply in my post in MSDN forum.
Please refer [Could it be possible to extend UnitTestClass in Visual Studio 2010/2013 Professional Edition?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6ffaf34-0ce7-4e4e-859b-0cf5c285a695/could-it-be-possible-to-extend-unittestclass-in-visual-studio-20102013-professional-edition?forum=vsunittest#0a505304-c3c2-4d22-8904-62f91b84d19d)

Put simply, it's just a problem of Registry entry "AttributeProvider".

So if the assembly name of the test class attribute extention is "MyExtension.Simple.LoggingTestClass" and the full name of extended test class attribute is "MyExtension.Simple.LoggingTestClass.LoggingTestClassAttribute", the entry value should be as follows.
"AttributeProvider"="MyExtension.Simple.LoggingTestClass.LoggingTestClassAttribute, MyExtension.Simple.LoggingTestClass"

In my environment, with this setting, Visual Studio 2013 Professional runs the test which is qualified by my extended attribute.

That's all. thanks for you attention.

*ps. I have corrected the .reg file included in my source files and exchanged it. So if you have already downloaded, please re-download and exchange them.